# UiBinder - HTMLPanel vs. div

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder

Is there some sort of penalty when I'm using a `HTMLPanel` instead of a plain `div`?

E.g.

```
<g:HTMLPanel>
  <div>
    /* Widgets, more HTML */
  </div>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

in contrast to

```
<g:HTMLPanel>
  <g:HTMLPanel>
    /* Widgets, more HTML */
  </g:HTMLPanel>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Short answer:

When in doubt, look at the generated code (pass the `-gen` argument to the DevMode or Compiler)

## Long answer:

There will be a runtime performance penalty using a widget over a simple DOM element, always. And even more when that DOM element is created by parsing an HTML snippet.

When `UiBinder` sees a widget as a child of `HTMLPanel`, it will generate a placeholder `<span>` with a generate unique ID and then use the `HTMLPanel.addAndReplaceElement` to replace that placeholder with a widget.

So the second snippet will generate (approx)

```
HTMLPanel root = new HTMLPanel("<span id='uuid'></span>");
HTMLPanel child = new HTMLPanel("/* Widgets, more HTML. */");
root.addAndReplaceElement(child, "uuid");
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a performance penalty, but I think HTMLPanel is the only Widget that, within a UiBinder, can contain (as children) a mix of both Widget and HTML tags.